# Is it possible to both dispatch an array of actions and also navigate from an ngrx effect?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have an issue with one of my application's ngrx effects. I am basically trying to execute multiple actions using `concatMap()` **AND** navigate using the router store's `go()`.

Here is the effect:

```js
  @Effect()
  loadPersonalInfoAndSignin$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(session.ActionTypes.LOAD_PERSONAL_INFO)
    .map((action: LoadPersonalInfoAction) => action.payload)
    .do(sessionToken => {
      localStorage.setItem('authenticated', 'true');
      localStorage.setItem('sessionToken', sessionToken);
    })
    .switchMap(() => this.userAccountService
      .retrieveCurrentUserAccount()
      .concatMap(currentUserAccount => [
        new LoadUserAccountAction(currentUserAccount),
        new SigninAction(),
        new LoadMessagesAction({})
      ])
    )
    .mapTo(go(['/dashboard']));
```

If I remove the `.mapTo(go(['/dashboard']))`, then all three actions in the `concatMap` array are successfully dispatched to their corresponding effects.

I am therefore wondering why my `mapTo(go(...` is causing the last two actions in the array (i.e. `SigninAction` & `LoadMessagesAction`) not to be dispatched to their corresponding effects..

Can someone please help?

**edit**: Changing `mapTo` to `do` as follows:

```js
.do(go(['/dashboard']));
```

results in the following error:

```js
ERROR in /Users/julien/Documents/projects/bignibou/bignibou-client/src/app/core/store/session/session.effects.ts (55,9): Argument of type 'Action' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialObserver<SigninAction>'.
  Type 'Action' is not assignable to type 'CompletionObserver<SigninAction>'.
    Property 'complete' is missing in type 'Action'.
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `do` instead of the `mapTo` ?

Comment: No. I have not. Let me try.

Comment: I have edited my post to take into account your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `do` for the `go` call will not see the route changed. [`go` is an action creator](https://github.com/ngrx/router-store/blob/v1.2.5/src/actions.ts#L22-L26) and the action that it creates needs to be emitted from the effect for `@ngrx/router-store` to receive the action and effect the route change.

Also, the `mapTo` operator will ignore what it receives and will emit the value you've specified, so it's not appropriate, either.

Instead, you should include the action created by the `go` call in your `concatMap` array:

```ts
@Effect()
loadPersonalInfoAndSignin$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(session.ActionTypes.LOAD_PERSONAL_INFO)
  .map((action: LoadPersonalInfoAction) => action.payload)
  .do(sessionToken => {
    localStorage.setItem('authenticated', 'true');
    localStorage.setItem('sessionToken', sessionToken);
  })
  .switchMap(() => this.userAccountService
    .retrieveCurrentUserAccount()
    .concatMap(currentUserAccount => [
      new LoadUserAccountAction(currentUserAccount),
      new SigninAction(),
      new LoadMessagesAction({}),
      go(['/dashboard'])
    ])
  );
```

Comment: Thanks again for this comprehensive answer cartant!